# pandas.eval with a boolean series with missing data

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, eval, missing-data

## Description

I am using `pandas.eval` on a boolean series with missing data.

To do this I use an indexer to mark non-null values and `.loc` to only apply `.eval` on the rows with non-missing data.

Applying the logical not operator using the expression `~bool` or `not(bool)` returns -1 or -2.

I understand that this is because my boolean series is casted as object type because of the missing values, but I am wondering :

- Why the -1 and -2 output ?
- What would be the proper way to use `.eval` on a boolean series with missing data ?

## Example

Here is a reproducible example using pandas 0.20.3.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bool': [True, False, None]})
    bool
0   True
1  False
2   None

indexer = ~pd.isnull(df['bool'])
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: bool, dtype: bool

df.loc[indexer].eval('~bool')
0    -2
1    -1
Name: bool, dtype: object
```

Comment: But I kept getting Value Error

Comment: Why not do casting to bool before evaluating i.e `df.loc[indexer].astype(bool).eval('~bool')`. I too am curious why you got -2 and -1

Comment: I cannot cast because I may have non-boolean columns in there (eval applies to the whole dataframe and not to just a column). e.g. I want to be able to deal with `df.eval('~bool & (num > 1)')` where num is a numerical column.

Answer (score 2):

For `eval`, `~` maps to `op.invert` as [seen in the source code here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1f812e37f33bf79beacbbfd2b1e0fa38958006e2/pandas/core/computation/ops.py#L474).

> ```
> _unary_ops_syms = '+', '-', '~', 'not'
> _unary_ops_funcs = op.pos, op.neg, op.invert, op.invert
> _unary_ops_dict = dict(zip(_unary_ops_syms, _unary_ops_funcs))
> ```

Thus when your Series is of good old `object` type, what you're seeing here is

```
>>> ~True
-2
>>> ~False
-1

# or with your Series
>>> ~pd.Series(True, dtype='object')
0    -2
dtype: object
```

Where you want

```
>>> ~pd.Series(True)
0    False
dtype: bool
```

The outputs `~True -> -2` and `~False -> -1` are because `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python, and -2, -1 are the bitwise complements of 1 and 0 respectively.

---

The obvious solution is to either convert the Series to `bool` type beforehand with `astype(bool)` in an extra setp, or if for some reason you cannot do so before the `eval`,

```
>>> df.loc[indexer].eval('~bool.astype("bool")')
0    False
1     True
Name: bool, dtype: bool
```